# TypeScript: Easiest way to share code between projects

Tags: typescript, shared-libraries, monorepo

I'm writing both a React.js app and a React Native app with both of them as separate NPM packages in a Lerna monorepo. What I'm trying to do is have a "shared library" kind of project that would hold TypeScript files shared by both projects, and it looks like it is almost impossible to do in an easy and clean way.

If I create the shared library as an NPM package, even if I symlink it, I need to re-compile it any time it changes. I'm looking for a way to import the TypeScript files directly from the shared project into the compilation process of both the React.js and React Native App.

I also read about the tsconfig.json "paths" setting, and tried to do something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@shared-types/*": ["../@test-shared/test-shared-types/lib/*"]
    }
}
```

And then I tried to import a class like: import { x } from "@shared-types/Types"
But that doesn't work either, TypeScript says it can't resolve the module.

I don't know why doing something this simple is so difficult and I'm hoping that someone here has a nice, clean solution.

Comment: Have you considered using [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to build the shared library and the code specific to one of the two apps using a single `tsc -b` command?

Comment: Using project references I still have to actually compile the shared library, and the compilation process of the actual React.js app is handled by create-react-app.

Comment: I see, with `create-react-app` you can't control the build process for the app.  You could run `tsc --watch` on the library; that's a bit of a duct-taped setup but I guess that's what you have to live with if you want to stick with `create-react-app`.  Alternatively, I can try to help you get the "paths" approach to work (I'm not sure it will work); if you'd like to pursue that, please add information about your file layout and the output of the `traceResolution` compiler option to the question.